# Is it possible to use the scrypt command to encrypt all the files in a folder?

Tags: command-line, scrypt

I have already tried using scrypt for encrypting single files and it seems to be working quite well.

But what if I want to encrypt all the files in a folder?

According to man page scrypt is a tool for encrypting files.

Is there still a way to encrypt all the files in a folder?

Comment: Are you referring to encrypting the folder or each file individually?

Answer (score 1):

One can use `encfs` to encrypt a folder:

#### Method 1:

1. Install it:

   ```
   sudo apt install encfs
   ```
2. Create the required directories, one for the encrypted data and the other for accessing them:

   ```
   encfs ~/.encrypt ~/visible
   ```
3. Accept the requests made by `encfs` then give it a password of your liking.
4. Now place the files to protect in the `~/visible` folder.
5. To hide them run:

   ```
   fusermount -u ~/visible

   # This will hide all files in there.
   ```
6. To access them again run:

   ```
   encfs ~/.encrypted ~/visible

   # This will ask you for your password so the files
   # in ~/visible will be seen and accessed
   ```

Source:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FolderEncryption

#### Method 2:

Use `Gnome Encfs Manager`

1. Install:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gencfsm 
   sudo apt update 
   sudo apt install gnome-encfs-manager
   ```
2. To use run the `Gnome Encfs Manager` program to use GUI to achieve the same as in method 1.

#### Method 3:

Using a terminal script you can use `scrypt` to achieve this:

```
for i in /home/$USER/Documents/koko/*; do scrypt enc "$i" "$i-sc"; done
```

More information:

1. koko: My imaginary folder, yours should be different
2. You will have to enter the password for each encryption done

#### Method 4

For randomly generated passwords written into a file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running script..."
echo " "
echo "Please enter the names of folder to encrypt file contents"
echo "and folder to store the passwords for the files"    
echo " "

read -p 'Files location: ' folder
read -p 'Password storage location: ' passwdlocation
read -p 'name of password file: ' mypasswords
echo " "


if [[ -z "$folder" || -z "$passwdlocation" ]];then

    echo "Please supply the required folder names"
    exit 1

else

    if [ -d "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"" ]; then

        # If password folder exists ask user if it should be deleted
        read -n1 -p "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation" exists, delete Y or N?" doit
        echo 
        case "$doit" in
            y|Y)    rm -R /home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation" && mkdir /home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation";;
            n|N) echo "Script terminated by user" && exit 1;;
            *) echo
        esac
    else
        mkdir /home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"
    fi  

    # Is it a directory
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        # Make sure target folder has files in it
        if [ ! "$(ls -A "/home/$USER/Documents/"$folder"" 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]; then          

            # Check if password file already exists
            # if it does ask to delete of write to it
            if [ "$( ls -A "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"/"$mypasswords".txt" 2> /dev/null)" == "" ]; then

                read -n1 -p ""$mypasswords".txt already exists, delete Y or N? " doagain
                echo
                case "$doagain" in
                    y|Y)  rm -rf "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"/"$mypasswords".txt";;
                    n|N)  echo "file not deleted!";;
                    *) echo "Operation successful";;
                esac
        else

        fi

        for i in "$folder"/*
        do
            # Create random passwords
            filepasswd=$(strings /dev/urandom | grep -o '[[:alnum:]]' | head -n 30 | tr -d '\n';) 

            scrypt enc -P "$i" "$i-sc" <<< "$filepasswd"

            # Add password to password store location
            echo -n  "$i-sc  $filepasswd" >> "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"/"$mypasswords".txt"
            echo -e "\n" >> "/home/$USER/Documents/"$passwdlocation"/"$mypasswords".txt"
            echo "$i Done"
        done

    else
        echo "The target "$folder" is empty!"

        exit 1

    fi  


    else

        echo "Invalid arguments .. please supply directory names"
        exit 1

    fi

fi

echo "Script finished"
```

Comment: I have it already only trying to fine tune it... will update shortly

Comment: Hi George. I noticed the scrypt method in your answer now. I will try it tomorrow if I can and leave some feedback if it works.

Comment: Hi George. I noticed that you are the same cool dude that helped me the last time I asked about scrypt. That time I wanted to use the password from stdin in the one-liner. Now I am trying to combine both one-liners. Like so: for i in koko/*; do scrypt enc -P "$i" "$i-sc" <<< "passtest123"; done. However it doesn't quite seem to be working. When I used only your line it worked but I had to enter the password manually. Can we make this one-liner loop through all the files, encrypt them and also use the password from stdin in the same one-liner?

Comment: Be patient already on it when through will post after testing the script, and the one up there works. The folder has to be in you `/home/$USER` directory.. stay tuned